# File location for database created in MYSQL workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, file-location

I created a database in MySQL Workbench, but I can't find where it is located.
I searched the `xampp/mysql` folder and found a `db.opt` folder, but nothing else.
I also checked `programdata/mysql` and `programsX86/mysqlworkbench` and found nothing.

Comment: What is your mysql directory location?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Open Workbench
2. Open the appropriate MySQL connection (the one you used to create the database)
3. Open the "Management" tab in the Navigator (left pane)
4. Open "Server Status" under "Management" to view information about your MySQL server
5. Note the "Data Directory" path on that page

This is where your recently created database lives.

Comment: ok thanks. I have a bunch of .frm's and .ibd's how do i turn these into a .mdf?

Comment: Q: You didn't "create the database" by creating an .idb file, did you?  You used a tool.  Similarly, you'll *ALSO* use a tool (like MSSQL Data Studio) to *migrate* your database from mySQL to MSSQL.  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27453107/3135317).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using windows, you can found your mysql data in below directory. Suppose you have installed your mysql server in Programming files under C directory then your mysql data path should be.

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\mysql server version\data
```

In above directory you will get all created database folders with files.

Comment: I just have this folder in that location..
MySQL Installer for Windows
There is no data folder in the mysql folder

Comment: Is there any such type of directory in your C drive? `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\mysql server version\data`

Comment: I just have C:\ProgramData\MySQL inside the mysql folder is a folder titled "MySQL Installer for Windows"

Comment: Okay, do one thing go to mysql installatin directory that should be `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server vertison\` here you will find `my.ini` file open this file and find  the data directory location with name `datadir`.

Answer (score -1):

You likely didn't satisfy one of the requirements for "workbench" to be installed. Uninstall MySQL, and start the install process over. When you get a prompt something like "all of the requirements for the following programs have NOT been met"...check out what those requirements are. Usually something like a visual studio package. Go get that package, install it. Then start the MySQL install over again.