# how to extract mysql database as .mdf

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012

when I go to the database I created in mysql I just see a db.opt, .frm and .ibd file types. Is there a way to create a .mdf database file so I can further create my project in visual studio?

Comment: it looks like you are trying to convert a MySQL database to a SQL Server database. In order to "work", the SQL Server should have at least one .mdf and one .ldf files (at least 1 data and 1 log file). There are probably tools for that conversion, you should search further online.

Comment: Something is stopping you to work with MySql in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

To use a MySQL database in Visual Studio, you need to use Connector / Net and MySQL For Visual Studio. This code works well and will allow you to use MySQL with the various features of VS.

Or you need to transport the data from MySQL to SQL Server. There are tools to do that if you must.

See here. http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html

It is true that some MySQL databases have on-disk structures that use .frm and .ibd files. But those files are intended to be accessed pretty much exclusively by the MySQL server process.

It's also true that the mdf file is an ondisk structure for SQL Server. These files aren't transportable like .xls files or other "document" files.

Answer (score 0):

1) You do *NOT* want to "extract a MySQL database as an .mdf file".  Instead, you want to *export* a MySQL database to a SQL server database.

2) SQL Server uses any of the following files - at a minimum, you need a "primary database file" and a "log file".  But you absolutely need MSSQL to manage these files for you:

- .mdf - Primary database data file.
- .ndf - Other database data files i.e. non Primary.
- .ldf - Log data file.

3) So how do you export?  If you're familiar with MSSQL SSMS (the MSSQL GUI), you might want to consider using the Export/Import Wizard.  Here is a good "howto" on using MSSQL "import" tools:

- http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2205/mysql-to-sql-server-data-migration/

4) Alternatively, you can also use phpAdmin to "export" into MSSQL:

- http://www.waynezim.com/2010/03/how-to-export-mysql-database-to-mssql-using-phpmyadmin/

5) Finally, if all you want to do is access mySQL data from an MSVS C# or ASP.Net program ... there's really no need to export/import at all. .Net allows you to access mySQL data directly:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio.html

Good luck - and let us know what you find works best for you!